# Go - Unmarshal XML, Attribute issues

Tags: go, xml-parsing

Maybe somebody could give some insight here... I seem to be hitting a brick wall with the encoding/XML library.

For the life of me, I can't replicate the valid XML attributes from < gpx >
Basically i'm unmarshalling the XML data from a GPS file, then marshalling it back into another file. Everything is working correctly, except the attribute tags for the root XML < gpx >

I've tried various

```
func (c *gpx) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {}
```

type approaches to no avail.

Basically I just want the root tag < GPX > to have all the attributes assigned correctly. Why you can't do Attributes []xml.Attr xml:",attr"or something similar is beyond me.

Good XML header -> http://pastebin.com/XjEZuBa1

I can't link the bad XML header, since I'm a new member.. but the XML unmarshal/marshal process adds _ to the namespace which causes issues, among other things.

GO Playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/J7wy6306Cj

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a tip, adding a [Playground](http://play.golang.org/) link with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps people help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have put some code into the Go Playground. I believe this replicates the issue I am having.       http://play.golang.org/p/J7wy6306Cj

Comment: Is your issue those `_xmlns:foo` that should be `xmlns:foo`?

Comment: The namespace is one of the issues, but the output XML attributes is quite different than incoming attributes. For example, if I run my program on a gigantic GPS file, it will not import into Garmin Basecamp until I replace the < gpx > header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the default Go XML encoder cannot encode stuff like

```
xmlns:foo="http://example.com/Foo-V1" foo:attr="bar"
```

As [the code shows](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7bc40ffb05d8813bf9b41a331b45d37216f9e747/src/encoding/xml/marshal.go#L333), it chooses the name based on the URL, and you can't just define namespaces yourself. The Go encoder emits code like this which, AFAIK, is basically equivalent to the one above:

```
xmlns:Foo-V1="http://example.com/Foo-V1" Foo-V1:attr="bar"
```

The only thing that is different here is the prefix for the namespace.

As for forward-declaration of other namespaces, I'd suggest only declaring them on elements and attributes that need them. I.e. to encode something like

```
<foo xmlns:bar="http://example.com/Bar-V1">
  <bar:elem>Hello world</bar:elem>
</foo>
```

use structs like this

```
type Foo struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"foo"`
    BarElem BarElem
}

type BarElem struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://example.com/Bar-V1 elem"`
    Data    string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

which serializes to

```
<foo>
  <elem xmlns="http://example.com/Bar-V1">Hello world</elem>
</foo>
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/79bhk70yFj.

Comment: Accepted answer. You're right, it's a limitation with the XML encoder of Go. Unfortunately Garmin Basecamp is very persnickety with how the XML attributes are represented. As such, I performed some basic string manipulation to get the desired results. Unfortunate, because other languages (not mentioning any names) could easily give the required results.